# Run-time error '1004' Range.boarders

Tags: vba, excel

Receiving an error with this segment of code.  I am using code from Excel 2010 worksheet, where it works without issue, on an Excel 2013 computer.  All of my libraries have updated correctly and we are not sure why this does not seem to be forward compatible.

```
With Me.Range("T3:Y196")

    .borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    .borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
    .borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick    '<--- error here
    .borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick      '<--- once above code is commented out error occurs here

End With
```

Also receiving an error here:

```
With Range(ConvertColumnNumberToLetter(questionTextCol - 1) & CStr(myRow) & ":" & ConvertColumnNumberToLetter(instructionsCol) & CStr(myRow)).borders(xlEdgeTop)
'above Range gives same result as "T3:Y196" but I hard coded it to do some testing in the previous With Statement
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous    '<--- Error
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium           '<--- Error
End With
```

Now, both `.LineStyle` and `.Weight` work in other areas of the code so we are not sure what to do about this.

When I record a macro I get this:

```
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
```

When I add the range in it works to perfection (again this is on a clean sheet):

```
With Range("C2:I20")
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
End With
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `.borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick` works for me in `xl2013`

Comment: I figured this would happen, cannot figure out what its wrong here

Comment: Did you copy the code directly from VBA? If yes then I am curious as to why the `b` in `.borders` is in small letters. Are you using any variable wirth that name?

Comment: yes I did copy directly from VBA and I noticed it was lower case as well. No variables even close to that name.

Comment: `With Me.Range(ConvertColumnNumberToLetter(questionIDcol + 1) & CStr(questionsHeaderRow + 1) & ":" & ConvertColumnNumberToLetter(instructionsCol) & CStr(lastRow))
        .Interior.Color = vbWhite
        .borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlDot
        .borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
        .borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlDot
        .borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
        .Interior.ThemeColor = 1
    End With` is in the same Sub and works

Comment: any procedure names? May I see your excel file if possible? if yes, can you upload it to www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to share the file as it is proprietary to my client.

Comment: What about any procedure/function name with `borders` do a ctrl+F on that word and search the entire vba project

Comment: oh found a variable in another sub in a module and not one of the sheets that is named borders. I will work with that and see if that fixes the issue. thanks!

Comment: ok changed the name of the variable and they all changed to `.Borders` however I am receiving my first error at the same position in the with statement.

Comment: Next do the same check for `xlEdgeRight` as well.

Comment: Nothing for `xlEdgeRight` or `Weight`

Comment: What I'm going to do is have my coworkers send me a clean version that is working on their laptop once they change the variable name of borders and see if that might fix it... if they ever show up to work haha

Comment: Do let us know :) With the current scenario (where you are not able to share the workbook) I don't think I would be of more help to you then I have have already suggested

Comment: Nada... I checked the definition of `.Borders` (member of Range), `xlEdgeRight` (member of xlBordersIndex), `.Weight` (member of Borders), and `xlThick` (member of XlBorderWeight). I attempted to change `xlEdgeRight` and `xlThick` to their numerical values of 10 and 4 respectively as well.  All still return `Run-time error '1004'  Application defined or object-defined error`.

Comment: Are any of the cells protected?

Comment: Nope, nothing is protected on the sheets yet, still in development stage

Comment: A good way to test these sorts of errors is to highlight the range in the UI and see what exactly is enabled and what isn't. My bet is that the given answer below is spot-on and you have merged cells in the right-hand extent of your range.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but instead of using with Me.Range try setting a sheet object and working from there. I tend to get less glitching this way. example

```
    Dim TheSheet as Worksheet
    Set TheSheet = Sheets("Your Sheet Name")
    With TheSheet.Range("T3:Y196")
         .borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
         .borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
         .borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick    '<--- error here
         .borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick  
    End With
```

The only other thing I can think of is merged cell issues, where half the cell is in the set range, and half the cell is not.

Comment: Attempted changing the sheet name several ways, none of which work correctly.  Eventually found the range to the right and did `xlEdgeLeft` and the bottom and did `xlEdgeTop` which work for whatever reason.